# Table Height 100% inside Div element

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to set table height 100% to its parent div without define height in div. My code is not working. I dont know what I am missing. Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6bqkL/344/)

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
<div style="float:left">a<br />b</div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" style="border:solid 1px #000000">
<tr>
<td valign="middle">c</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Not setting a height on an empty div means no height, so setting 100% of 0 is 0...

Comment: Div height expend according to its content, So whatever its height same height should be on table

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not possible without assigning height value to div.

Add this

```
body, html{height:100%}
div{height:100%}
table{background:green; width:450px}    ​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6bqkL/346/)**

Comment: NO. Body height should be 100% to specify 100% height for any div inside it

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a height in the div `<div style="overflow:hidden">` else it doesnt know what `100%` is.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it-

HTML-

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:100%">
     <div style="float:left">a<br>b</div>
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:100%;">     
          <tr><td>This is the content of a table that takes 100% height</td></tr>  
      </table>
 </div>
```

CSS-

```
html,body
{
    height:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}
table
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehDUq/2/)

**Update:** Well, if you are not looking for applying 100% height to your parent containers, then here is a jQuery solution that should help you-

[**Demo**-*using jQuery*](http://jsfiddle.net/ehDUq/4/)

Script-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var b= $(window).height(); //gets the window's height, change the selector if you are looking for height relative to some other element
    $("#tab").css("height",b);
});
```

Comment: we cant use body and html height 100% because it will affect my old html

Comment: Without specifying the height of the parent element you cant take up the 100% height. You should look up for a jQuery or Javascript solution then

Comment: I have updated the answer with a jQuery solution. See if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. My solution was to give the inner table a fixed height of 1px and set the height of the td in the inner table to 100%. Against all odds, it works fine, tested in IE, Chrome and FF!

Answer (score -4):

to set height of table to its container I must do:

1) set "position: absolute"

2) remove redundant contents of cells (!)

Comment: What? `position: absolute ` has nothing to do with this. Could you explain why you think it does?

Comment: I don't "think". I did as I wrote