# Table not getting resized inside a div on resizing the div

Tags: html, jsp, html-table

I have a table in my jsp inside a div which is resizeable.
When I'm resizing the div, I'm not able to resize the height of table inside where as width of table is getting resized. Following is my snippet. Please check once.

```
<div id="id" style="height:350px; width250px;" class="control">

    <div id="fifth_heading" class="heading_control">
        <i class="fa2 fa-fifth"></i>
        <p><%=entry1.getDivdescription() %></p>
        <div class="button_right_second">
            <i class="fa3 fa-second3" id="<%=entry1.getDivid() %>"></i>             
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fifth_dropdown">
        <div class="table_data" id="table_second">

        <table id="example3"  style="height:auto;"class="display" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <!-- the below tr prints the dates -->
        <tbody>
            <tr  id="line1">
            <td>
                <span id="header_title">Your Current Lead Time</span>             
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="line2">
            <td>
                <span id="value">alignvalue</span>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



div.table_data{margin-left:2px;margin-right:10px;margin-top:5px;overflow:auto;}
#table_second::-webkit-scrollbar{
width:10px;
background-color:#cccccc;
} 
#table_second::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color:rgb(78, 82, 93);
border-radius:10px;
}
#table_second::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:rgb(78, 82, 93);
border:1px solid #333333;
}
#table_second::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:rgb(78, 82, 93);
border:1px solid #333333;
}
```

Comment: If the height of your table is already set to be `100%` and its not working, what are the CSS properties used of the `.fifth_dropdown`, `.table_data`, or `#table_second`? Can you include those CSS scripts to your post?

Comment: for fifth_dropdown,nothing i have added,and for table_data,i have pasted.and for #table_second,i have added css only for scrollers.please review them once.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of your table to 100% and explicitly setting the div's height.

Answer as per this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877302/table-height-100-inside-div-element)

Comment: i m setting div height on basis of value from db and then resizing the whole div .main div is getting shorten in height but not the table

Comment: If the data inside the table is getting cut off, that is normal. You'll have to adjust your data inside the table or perhaps use something like DataTables.

Try giving the div a background color (e.g. green) and the table another background color (e.g. red) to see if the table really is scaling along with the parent container div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which `<div>` you want to resize but you can try one of these...

If you want to resize the `<div id="id" ... class="control">` to make your `<table>` resized, try to add the `height` property in your `div.table_data` with `% percent` unit.

If you like to resize your `<div>` and `<table>`, you must set the height your `<div>` with class `control`, `div.table_data` and your `<table>` to `100%` or any value (from 0-100) with `% percent` unit.

My code snippet after doing that...

CSS

```
div.table_data
{
margin-left:2px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top:5px;
overflow:auto;
height:70%;
background-color:#ccffcc;
}
```

(Excluded the `-webkit-scrollbar`)

HTML

```
<div id="id" style="height:100%; width250px;background-color:#ff9999;" class="control">

    <div id="fifth_heading" class="heading_control">
        <i class="fa2 fa-fifth"></i>
        <p>dddddddd</p>
        <div class="button_right_second">
            <i class="fa3 fa-second3" id="ddd"></i>             
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fifth_dropdown">
        <div class="table_data" id="table_second">

        <table id="example3"  style="height:100%;" class="display" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <!-- the below tr prints the dates -->
        <tbody>
            <tr  id="line1">
            <td>
                <span id="header_title">Your Current Lead Time</span>             
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="line2">
            <td>
                <span id="value">alignvalue</span>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This snippet can make the two `<div>` and your `<table>` will be re-sized when the window is re-sized.

---

If you don't like that your `<table>` will be too small if the size of your window is too small, you can use the `min-height` CSS property. For bigger sizes, use `max-height`.