# How to make a nested table the same height as its parent

Tags: html, css

I have an html table nested inside an outer one.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #FF0000;"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table border="1" >
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I'd like is for the inner table height to expand to match the height of the row of the outer table. I've tried setting the inner table with a style that has height:100%, as I've seen suggested elsewhere, but it doesn't work:

https://jsfiddle.net/twistedlizard/ghnyton9/

Could anyone tell me the technique?

Comment: Just FYI table layouts are *so* 1996...there's probably a way better way to do it.  But don't let that stop you from learning the answer to this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `height` to parent element.

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #FF0000;"/>
     </td>
     <td style="padding: 0; height:100%">
        <table border="1" style="height:100%;">
           <tr>
             <td>A</td>
             <td>B</td>
             <td>C</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the nested table a css class en set it's height and max height and min height  on  100 %
Tables are not outdated as long as you use them to show data as in a grid not for layouting stuff.  Hope this helps

Edit =》 try display :inline -Block if all else fails

Answer (score 0):

As per this question: [Table Height 100% inside Div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877302/table-height-100-inside-div-element)

It seems the container needs an explicit height. Adding a height to the containing `td` appears to work as desired, though I'm not sure that is a reasonable requirement for your situation.