# Height of the iframe content grows with each iframe resize to fit content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, resize

I want to resize an iframe to fit its content, but every time I do this, the height of the content increases by a constant value, and I need resize iframe again. And so on.

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/theBerrigan/pen/wvBZMQd)**

HTML:

```html
<iframe style="width: 100%; max-width: 400px; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;"></iframe>
```

JS:

```js
const html = `<div>
      line 1<br>
      line 2<br>
      <table style="width:100%; height:100%;">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: center; background: #ddd;">table content</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>`;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin = 0;
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div id="root">                             <!-- iframe will be resized by its offsetHeight -->
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>        <!-- clear fix, just in case -->
        <div id="content-root">${ html }</div>  <!-- custom content goes here -->
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>        <!-- clear fix, just in case -->
    </div>`;

    const rootEl = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('#root');

    // Resize iframe with interval.
    // Since the content of the iframe is not changing, 
    // the height of the iframe should not change starting from the second iteration
    setInterval(() => {
        iframe.style.height = rootEl.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" to HTML.

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; max-width: 400px; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" ></iframe>
```

Remove below from java script.

```
, 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is the content of the iframe overflows it’s body element. Try setting overflow hidden on the body element in the iframe.

If that does’t work then you need to look for another method to calculate the size of your content. Or look more closely at the css in the iframe.

You could have a look at the source code to a library called iframe-resizer that contains a number of different ways to do this and just lift the one that works for you

Comment: Just looked closer at your code, take the `height: 100%` off your table

Comment: Yep, table has `height: 100%` relative to height of parent `div` that has no `height` style. So table height shouldn't work in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877302/table-height-100-inside-div-element/13877363). Or I'm wrong?

Comment: It would be relative to the size of the iframe, so resizing the iframe resizes the table which then triggers the iframe to resize And around you go.